# Anatomy of joints of human hand

Tags: human-anatomy, joints, locomotion

Q) A girl slipped and is falling. She puts out her arms to prevent falling. Which joints are most affected by her fall?

1. Fibrous and Synovial joints.
2. Cartilagenous and Synovial joints.
3. Fibrous and Cartilaginous joints.

The answer is 1.

Attempt:
Since it is the arms that will be affected, Synovial joints will be affected. But I don't remember there being any fibrous or cartilaginous in hands.

**Are there any fibrous or cartilaginous joints in hand?**

Comment: What does "cartilaginous joints" mean? That seems really imprecise.

Answer (score 1):

**The intermediate radio-ulnar joint is fibrous in arms.**

[image]

<sup>[[Source: Slideshare.net]](https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/hermizan84/shoulder-joint-humerus)</sup>

You can see the the interosseus membrane between radius and ulna which is composed of white collagen fibres.

Furthermore, there is a cartilaginous joint between epiphysis and diaphysis of humerus which is made up of hyaline cartilage. But it is lost during development and is absent in adults.